# Wordpress get related pages (tag based) - wp_get_post_tags

Tags: wordpress, tags

Works when I put in `single.php` but not in `page.php`, how is that?

Can anyone enlighten me please?

I'm working on Wordpress theme and want to echo all the tags of a page.

The code:

```
<?php
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
$tag_ids = array();
foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;

$args=array(
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'showposts'=>5, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>';
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
$my_query->the_post();
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
echo '</ul>';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On page.php `wp_get_post_tags($post->ID)` tries to get tags for page. Wordpress is not supporting page tags. To have such option you have to add tags for pages, do it with  [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-tagger/) or add code following one of many [tutorials](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-tags-and-categories-to-your-wordpress-page)